# How do I store say a file path that can be changed at runtime in Delphi

Tags: file, delphi

My program allows the user to change the location of the main set of files. Currently I have a text file with a fixed location that contains the folder location of the other files. However, this seems to almost defeat the purpose. Is there a better way of storing this file path?

Comment: Delphi has handling to access the Windows registry, so you could store the setting there, maybe?

Comment: In Samples\Delphi\DataSnap\ProxyGenerator\ProxyGeneratorSettings.pas investigate the methods LoadSettings and SaveSettings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi contains the [TRegistry](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry) class, which makes it very simple to save and retrieve your settings information from the Windows Registry.

```
uses
  Registry;

const
  RegKey = 'Software\Your Company\Your App\';

procedure TForm1.SaveSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  DataDir: string;
begin
  // Use the result of SelectDirectory() or whatever means you use
  // to get the desired location from the user here. ExtractFilePath()
  // is only used as an example - it just gets the location of the
  // application itself and then appends a subdirectory name to it.
  DataDir:= ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Data\';
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    if Reg.OpenKey(RegKey, True) then
      Reg.WriteString('DataDir', DataDir);
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    if Reg.OpenKey(RegKey, False) then
      Label1.Caption := Reg.ReadString('DataDir');
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As @SirRufo mentions in the comments, Delphi also has the [TRegistryIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistryIniFile), which serves as a wrapper around the registry functions, allowing you to use it without any knowledge of the registry structure. (It's use is similar to that of TIniFile/TMemIniFile, which I'm describing next.)

If you prefer not to use the Registry, you can also use INI (text files) pretty easily. Delphi has support for standard (WinAPI based) INI files in [TIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile), as well as it's own (and IMO better implemented) [TMemIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile). Both are fairly compatible, so I'll demonstrate using just the TMemIniFile here.

(Locations used for reading/writing are for simplicity. In reality, you should use the appropriate subfolder of the `%APPDATA%` directory, obtained by the appropriate call to [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` or `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` constant.)

```
uses
  IniFiles;

// Writing
var
  Ini: TMemIniFile;
  RootDir: string;
begin
  RootDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(TheFile);
  try
    Ini.WriteString('Settings', 'DataDir', RootDir + 'Data\');
    Ini.UpdateFile;
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;

// Reading
var
  Ini: TMemIniFile;
  RootDir: string;
begin
  RootDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(TheFile);   // The file is your ini file name with path
  try
    DataDir := Ini.ReadString('Settings', 'DataDir', RootDir);
    if DataDir = '' then
      DataDir := RootDir;  // No user specified location. Use app's dir
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [`TRegistryIniFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistryIniFile) is also worth to be mentioned here

Comment: @SirRufo: Right you are. I've added a paragraph about it and a link to the docs to my answer (with proper credit given to you for the suggestion). Thanks. :-)

Comment: `TRegIniFile` is internally used by `TRegistryIniFile` which inherits from `TCustomIniFile`. I would suggest to use the latter to easily switch between file-based or registry-based access

Comment: @SirRufo: Oops! Grabbed the wrong link. Fixed. Once again, thanks. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help , this really helps. However, I don't get the purpose of using ExtractFilePAth() and are Datadir and DataPath meant to be the same thing in the registry example?

Comment: @user3178819 Yes, the registry sample has a typo. I'll fix it. :-) The ExtractFilePath() was simply to retrieve the location of your executable file. (It's just demo code - you can use the file location specified by the user as a result of `SelectDirectory` instead, for instance.)

Answer (score 2):

I very much prefer inifiles. Your users can easily read and edit them if needed, you can keep all information neatly together, and you can easily copy or install configurations to other machines. Inifiles are so simple that you can easily parse them on platforms other than windows, and with any language.

Nowadays many people start using sqlite as some sort of filesystem replacement. They store settings, data files, history, logging, translations, etc all in an sqlite database. That happens on all platforms, even on mobile and embedded devices.
It takes a bit more to set it up, but after that it's pretty flexible.